# DCH Proxy detected by my spam checker

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, spam-prevention

I'm trying a tool for detecting proxy connection, one of the ip address was detected as DCH Proxy, but what does it means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DCH could refer to Data Center, Content Delivery Network or Hosting Provider. It is wide range of servers, but it does not guarantee to be proxy.

Reference Source: https://www.ip2location.com/databases/px4-ip-proxytype-country-region-city-isp